# CMAccelerometerData class Vs. deprecated UIAccelerometer class

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, accelerometer

Based on [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAccelerometerData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation, the **CMAccelerometerData class** (found in the Core Motion framework) has a property of type **CMAcceleration** called ***acceleration*** that is a typedef of a struct containing 3 values (double x, double y, double z)

I'm rather new to Objective-C (I only know C++..) so my question is this : How do I access, let's say the *double y* value kept in that property, at some point during my code?

Do I first create an instance of the CMAccelerometerData class like this :

```
CMAccelerometerData *myAccelerometer;
```

then access its acceleration property :

```
double axisYvalue = [myAccelerometer acceleration];
```

the above is obviously wrong, isn't it? I have to get the Y found in acceleration specifically so how do I do that?

```
double axisYvalue = [myAccelerometer acceleration->y]; // no this is wrong as well..
```

so how do I do it?

And one last question if I may :)

given this specific class and property that I mentioned.. and let's say I've instantiated my CMAccelerometer class.. Now every time, during my code, I use something like

```
return [myAccelerometer acceleration->y]; // let's say that's the correct version :)
```

inside some -(double) method .. will I be getting the value of the Y-axis at ***that*** specific moment in which the call is being made ?

I am asking this because I got confused when reading about the now deprecated UIAccelerometer class where you had to define intervals and update the values of x,y,z every so often etc..
where as now I can get the value that is being exercised on the Y-axis the moment the call to the acceleration property is made, isn't that the case?

phew... sorry for the length of this text! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from C++, I assume it's safe to assume that you understand pointers. That first line:

```
CMAccelerometerData *myAccelerometer;
```

...isn't *creating* an instance, it's *declaring a pointer to* an instance, which won't point to anything valid. To get a valid instance, you'll never actually create one of these yourself. Instead, you'll use the [CMMotionManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class' `accelerometerData` property to get a pointer to a valid object:

```
// Sometime earlier...
CMMotionManager* manager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
[manager startAccelerometerUpdates];

// Sometime in the present...
// Get a ref to the most recent accelerometer data.
CMAccelerometerData* data = [manager accelerometerData];

// Access it.
double x = [data acceleration].x;
```

Comment: Yup I forgot to include that in my post. I wondered about it in my previous comment to Naveen Palli. But I wouldn't have thought I'd have to go that high up in the initialization process and initialize CMMotionManager instead, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I decided to post a relevant question in a new post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371399/how-do-i-compare-a-constant-to-an-newly-updated-accelerometer-value-each-time-ro

Answer (score 0):

You can access the readonly property

```
myAccelerometer.acceleration
```

this returns a struct of three doubles

```
myAccelerometer.acceleration.y (gives the y at that specific moment the call is being made)
```

Comment: :) perfect. one last thing (I repeat I'm new to Obj-C..) that I forgot to ask in my original post : CMAccelerometerData *myAccelerometer; creates an instance of the class or simply a pointer to an eventual instance of the class? Don't I have to add myAccelerometer = [[CMAccelerometerData alloc]init] ; before using myAccelerometer.acceleration.y ? confused..

Comment: This is correct. To put in C++ terms, CMAccelerometer *my.. only declares the variable. You will need to alloc, init (which is the equivalent of new) before using it. In fact you can say [myAcceleromater new] and it is the equivalent of [[myAccelerameter alloc] init]. There are some subtle things to wathc out and people prefer alloc, init.

Comment: Just note that `alloc/init` on a CMAccelerometerData class won't get you anything useful. You'll have to get one via a properly configured CMMotionManager instance.