# How do I compare a constant value to a continuously-updated Accelerometer value each time round a loop?

Tags: objective-c, ios, accelerometer

As it was suggested to me in [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369189/cmaccelerometerdata-class-vs-deprecated-uiaccelerometer-class) of mine, the following code takes the data coming from the accelerometer the "minute" the assignment : **CMAccelerometerData* data = [manager accelerometerData];** is performed, and *then* extracts from that data the acceleration exercised on the x-Axis and *stores* its value in a double (double x) :

```
 CMMotionManager* manager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

 CMAccelerometerData* data = [manager accelerometerData];

 double x = [data acceleration].x;
```

Suppose the value stored is 0.03 and suppose that I want to use it in a while loop as follows :

```
while (x > 0)
{
    // do something
}
```

the above loop will obviously run forever

*However*, what if I used the following code instead :

```
CMMotionManager* manager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

while([[manager accelerometerData] acceleration].x > 0) 
{
    // do something
}
```

wouldn't I be now comparing zero to a different value each time round the loop? 
(which is what I'm going for in my project anyway..)

any thoughts?

the reason I'm asking this is the following :

I want to check the values coming from the x-Axis over a certain period of time, rather than keep checking them at regular intervals, so I basically want to write a loop that would look something like this :

```
if ([[manager accelerometerData] acceleration].x > 0 ) 
{
    // initialiseTimer
}

while ([[manager accelerometerData] acceleration].x > 0 ) 
{
    if( checkTimer >=250ms )
    {
        stopTimer;

        printOut("X-Axis acceleration  was greater than zero for at least 250ms");

        breakFromLoop;
     }
}
```

I know the code in my 2nd if-block isn't valid Objective-C..This was just to give you an idea of what I'm going for..

Comment: Is this looking for positive acceleration or do you really mean to check if there is any non zero acceleration? Also what physical action are trying to detect. It's natural frequency will help to determine how often you should sample the accelerometer. My feeling is that you are sampling much faster than you need to.

Comment: There's no natural frequency in what I'm looking for even though there's obviously physical movement involved. Imagine grabbing your iPhone, stretching your arm out, device parallel to the ground and start moving your arm from right to left. Once 250ms have passed with you doing that, I want the iPhone to play sound. This is not the actual app (sounds ridiculous I know) but just to give you an idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a simple solution.

1)Declare an instance variable x that you update each time the accelerometer tell you to.

2)Compare this x to whatever value you need in the loop .

Hope this helps.

Regards,

George

Comment: If I left it to the accelerometer to do the checking it would update the value x every 0.10ms (I think this is as fast as it can go when it comes to updating) if I'm not mistaken, which means that if the loop goes back to the top sooner than that, it would be comparing the same value x to zero. Now such errors over a period of 250 ms would yield wrong results..

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant this: you start your loop in which you check this value. You can call this as fast as you want. But in this loop check the ivar x which gets modified by the accelerometer.

Comment: In fact, now that I read your question again, I think the second code is ok. It would be a good idea to try to update the CMMotionManager instead of alloc-ing a new object every time.

Comment: hmm.. I'm still not sure what you meant on your 1st comment. What do you mean by "you can call it as fast as you want"? I'll be calling for a new value as soon as the loop reaches back to the top and goes to check the while-condition. The way I've written the 2nd alternative version of the code, makes the checking of the accelerometer immediate, on the spot, right at the very "moment" the while-condition is checked, doesn't it?

Comment: and isn't that the behavior you want?

Comment: The behavior I want is the one where I use the " while ([[manager accelerometerData] acceleration].x > 0 ) " version so that every time I enter/renter the loop the accelerometer is checked and a new value is grabbed at that very instance. But I got confused when you said "as fast as you want" as if I can define how fast it will take for the loop to execute and then go back and grab a new Accelerometer-value.. Anyway, I think it was just confusion.. :)

Comment: You can check every x seconds if you want. That's what I was referring to. By creating an NSTimer , you can call a method at a desired interval.

Comment: oh, ok I see.. just to clarify, the Timer I'm using in my while loop is different from the one you're talking about, it's just a timer counting how much time has passed while the condition of the while-loop is true.. I'd really like to know whether the code I'm proposing is 100% correct or whether the iOS would oppose to such regular checks on the accelerometer and crash, before actually implementing it though..

Comment: Yes, that is ok. In addition to that, as a good practice, I would envelope the loop in a try-catch statement. This will just log exceptions for you if any, instead of having the app crash.